# Cannot install OpenCV in the same conda environment as PyTorch

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, conda

I have a conda enviornment named 'pytorch-train' where I have PyTorch with all CUDA related packages. When I try to install OpenCV in this environment it takes forever to solve the environment and it never reaches the end of the solving process.

The command for installing pytorch in my case is:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

The command for installing opencv is

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I've try reinstalling every tool and the result is that they can be installed independently but not in the same environment.

Comment: Have you activated the conda environment yet? also have you tried `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: is there an error message or is conda simply unable to figure this out? perhaps ditch conda and use pip

Comment: I've read against mixing conda with pip. The environment is activated and it doesn't prompt an error, it just never figures out what to do. I would really like to solve this issue..